# How to unsubscribe from file channel in Spring Integration?

Tags: spring, spring-integration

I would like to know how to unsubscribe from file channel. I was trying to direct channel and invoke unsubscribe method in my service but I don't have access to message handler and I was using `FileReadingMessageSource`. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to show your configuration but generally you want to stop the SourcePollingChannelAdapter that references the source to stop the adapter. You don't want to unsubscribe, that will cause errors unless the adapter is stopped.

**EDIT**

With your configuration, if the inbound adapter is in a class called `IntegrationCongfig`, it's bean name will be `integrationConfig.test.inboundChannelAdapter` (note lower case `i`)...

```
@Autowired
@Qualifier("integrationConfig.test.inboundChannelAdapter")
private SourcePollingChannelAdapter test;

@Autowired
private StandardIntegrationFlow processFileFlow;
```

...

```
this.test.stop();             // stop the adapter
this.processFileFlow.stop();  // stops all components in the flow
```

Stopping the flow will unsubscribe the handler from the channel; but you MUST stop the adapter first.

Comment: Here is my config: @Bean
 public MessageChannel fileInputChannel() {return new DirectChannel();}@Bean
 public IntegrationFlow processFileFlow() { return IntegrationFlows
         .from"fileInputChannel"
         .handle("incomingFileProcessor", "validateAndStartJob").get();
 }@Bean
 @InboundChannelAdapter(value = FILE_INPUT_CHANNEL, poller = @Poller(fixedDelay = _1000))
    public FileReadingMessageSource test(@Value("${dirPath}")String directory) { return monitorDirectory(directory);}

Comment: Don't put code in comments; as you can see it's hard to read; in future, edit the question instead and add a comment that you have done so. See the edit to my answer.